# Group proof with Modular arithmetic

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $G=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and we define an operation $*$ on $G$ by $a*b=ab$, the 
remainder of $ab\bmod 7$.

For instance, $$2*4=8=1$$  $$5*6=30=2$$

I want to show that $(G, *)$ is a group.

I know how to show that is has a binary operation, so every result of the operation is inside $G$.

I also know how to prove the inverse. However, how to show that it is associative and has an identity element?

Comment: For the identity, you need $a*e=e*a=a$ for all $a$ in $G$.  Can you think of which element of $G$ would satisfy that requirement?

Comment: would the identity element be just 1?

Comment: Right, very good.

Comment: For the associative property, you can use that ($\mathbb{Z}_7, \cdot)$ is a group in itself, so $(a \cdot b) \cdot c = a \cdot (b  \cdot c)$, ($mod \ 7$)

Comment: @chelivery what are you talking about? The element $0\in\Bbb Z_7$ doesn't have an inverse, so it's not a group under multiplication

Comment: Chelivery : firstly it's $(\mathbb{Z}_7 ^*, \cdot)$ that's a group, and secondly, do you think that if OP knew that it was, he would be asking this question ? He obviously has just begun studying groups, and so it's a good exercise trying to prove precisely what you're telling him to use

Comment: Alex: you're right, I meant without the $0$ as Max corrected (I was thinking of the field). Also I guessed he already knew some examples of groups that he could use such as those.

Comment: I'm curious how you are happy to prove the inverse without knowing the identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was incorrect, see the answer below

Comment: This answer is not correct. The group he describes is not what you say it is and it is definitely not a field.

Comment: It should form a field if we include the typical notion of addition, right? I made that change.

Comment: @TylerKharazi It needs the additive identity as well

Comment: Absolutely not right. It is simple enough to check the axioms of a field, and check that what OP describes does not satisfy all of them. You should remove your answer.

Comment: You're right. I can't delete the answer if it has been accepted though. I can edit out the field bit.

Answer (score 1):

To prove associativity, consider the fact that you are multiplying integers together and then reducing modulo 7 (in your words - finding the remainder).

The remainder will not change if you change the order of multiplication, because multiplication of integers is associative.

I believe your problem with the identity is solved in the comments.

EDIT: Your group is NOT a field. $\mathbb{Z}_7$ is different to the group which you describe.